# Delete a certain tag with a certain id content from an HTML using python BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, tags, beautifulsoup

I got a suggestion to use BeautifulSoup to delete a tag with a certain id from an HTML. For example, deleting `<div id=needDelete>...</div>` Below is my code, but doesn't seem to be working correctly:

```
import os, re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

cwd = os.getcwd()
print ('Now you are at this directory: \n' + cwd)

# find files that have an extension with HTML
Files = os.listdir(cwd)
print Files

def func(file):
    for file in os.listdir(cwd):
        if file.endswith('.html'):
            print ('HTML files are \n' + file)
            f = open(file, "r+")
            soup = BeautifulSoup(f, 'html.parser')
                matches  = str(soup.find_all("div", id="jp-post-flair"))
                #The soup.find_all part should be correct as I tested it to             
                #print the matches and the result matches the texts I want to delete.
                f.write(f.read().replace(matches,''))
                #maybe the above line isn't correct
            f.close()
func(file)
```

Would you help check which part has the wrong code and maybe how should I approach it?
Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`.decompose()` method](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#decompose) to remove the element/tag:

```
f = open(file, "r+")

soup = BeautifulSoup(f, 'html.parser')
elements = soup.find_all("div", id="jp-post-flair")
for element in elements:
  element.decompose()

f.write(str(soup))
```

It's also worth mentioning that you can probably just use the `.find()` method because an `id` attribute should be unique within a document (which means that there will likely only be one element in most cases):

```
f = open(file, "r+")

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')
element = soup.find("div", id="jp-post-flair")
if element:
  element.decompose()

f.write(str(soup))
```

---

As an alternative, based on the comments below:

- If you only want to parse and modify part of the document, BeautifulSoup has a [`SoupStrainer` class](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#parsing-only-part-of-a-document) that allows you to selectively parse parts of the document.
- You mentioned that the indentations and formatting in the HTML file was being changing. Rather than just converting the `soup` object directly into a string, you can check out the relevant [output formatting section](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#output-formatters) in the documentation.

  Depending on the desired output, here are a few potential options:

  - `soup.prettify(formatter="minimal")`
  - `soup.prettify(formatter="html")`
  - `soup.prettify(formatter=None)`

Comment: Hi Josh, thank you for answering my question! I tried your last way of using `decompose()`, but I got this error: "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'decompose'". So is decompose() not supposed to be used this way?

Comment: @Penny - Did the first one work? Without seeing your full code, it looks like `soup.find("div", id="jp-post-flair")` wasn't selecting any elements... probably because the element didn't exist in the HTML (which meant that it returned `None`, and the `.decompose()` method will throw an error then). I updated the answer and added a simple conditional statement.

Comment: HI @Josh, unfortunately the first one didn't work either.. For the second one, I tested it by writing the code as `elements = soup.find_all("div, id="jp-post-flair")` then `print elements`. It returns the correct elements I want. However, if i use `soup.find("div, id="jp-post-flair").decompose()`, I would receive that error message.

Comment: @Penny - I prepared [an example here](https://ideone.com/6iQje1) demonstrating the first option, and it works as expected. The `.decompose()` method will remove instances of the element from the original `soup` object... maybe the wrong variable is being referenced?

Comment: @Penny - And here is [an example](https://ideone.com/nrOUA2) demonstrating the usage of the second option.

Comment: Thank you @Jose! I tried your first example by printing `soup`. The correct content was returned in the terminal! But when I change the `print soup` to `f.write(soup)`, the original HTML didn't get the selected content removed. I guess I'll need to figure out how to remove the content form the original file next? Sorry that I'm new in scripting, so have a lot of research to do. :)

Comment: @Penny - Interesting... are you converting the BeautifulSoup document object into a string when writing it? (i.e., `f.write(str(soup))`)?

Comment: thank you! I tried `f.write(str(soup))`, it added duplicated content into the original file, so I wrote `newHTML = open('new.html', 'w')` and `newHTML.write(str(soup))` to write into a new file! It worked. However, I'm not sure if it's the module's problem - there are some new tags like `<img><p>` added to the new file right after the deleted content which doesn't exist in the source. Also, the structure/indentation of the original file is not well maintained. I'm not sure if it's the limit of the module..Maybe there's a way to maintain the indentations?

Comment: @Penny - You could try using another parser. Currently it looks like you're using `html.parser`, you could try `lxml` -> `soup = BeautifulSoup(f, 'lxml')`.  The parsers handle HTML differently, some are more strict than others. I know that `lxml` is more liniet, which means that it probably won't attempt to change your HTML as much as `html.parser`.. https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser

Comment: I just tried lxml parser, again, it still changed much content in the original HTML, such as a tag's attributes in many cases. Now I'm thinking about if I could switch to a different approach somehow - instead of writing the whole HTML file back into a new file, can I just replace that tag with an empty string/removing it directly from the original file?

Comment: @Penny - Yeah, good point. I will update the answer when I get a chance.

Comment: thank you for all the replies! Appreciate it! I'll also try with Regex's `sub` again see if it would work somehow.